# Have one sproc that debugger won't step into (SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition on Win7x64)

Tags: debugging, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm calling an sproc from SSMS, and that sproc calls a number of other ones. I can easily step through the outer sproc and, if I step-into, can walk through the sprocs being called. But one sproc simply won't be stepped into. Attempting to do so acts as if I stepped over it. That is, it runs without being stepped.

There is nothing at all remarkable about the sproc. It sets up a bunch of strings as SQL templates, then has a cursor used to get values (in a loop) that are used to populate the templates, and the resulting SQL is executed. It is identical in general form to other sprocs that I can step into.

Is it possible that there's some sort of flag for an sproc to prevent stepping into it? The outer sproc calls several other sprocs before it and, as I say, I can walk from the outer sproc into the inner ones without problem, other than this one. There is nothing particularly special about the code before this call - in fact, the immediate statement preceding it is a call to another sproc which I can walk into. That call returns normally, and then the problem sproc is called.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem procedure create using the `WITH ENCRYPTION` option by any chance?

There are also some limitations listed in the MSDN spec at [Transact-SQL Debugging Limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkyhd4yb.aspx), but none of them seem to apply to your case.